# Imports behave differently when in __init__.py that is imported

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import, python-internals

Imports in an `__init__.py` seem to behave differently when the file is run, to when it is imported.

If we have the following files:

`run.py`:

```
import test
```

`test/b.py`:

```
class B(object):
    pass
```

`test/__init__.py`:

```
from b import B
print B
print b
```

If we run `__init__.py` we get an error as I expect:

```
% python test/__init__.py

<class 'b.B'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
  print b
NameError: name 'b' is not defined
```

But if we `run.py` then we don't:

```
% python run.py 
<class 'test.b.B'>
<module 'test.b' from '~/temp/test/b.py'>
```

I would expect the behaviour to be the same. Why does this work?

This only works if we do it in an `__init__.py`. If we:

```
mv __init__.py a.py
touch __init__.py
```

and make `run.py`:

```
import test.a
```

Then we do get the error.

Comment: apologies for the wrong answer ...just removed it to not to create confusion.@Poke thanks for pointing it out...didn't noticed initially what you mentioned.

Answer (score 6):

The situation is the following: you have a script (`run.py`), a package `test` and its submodule `test.b`.

Whenever you import a submodule in Python, the name of that submodule is automatically stored into the parent package. So that when you do `import collections.abc` (or `from collections.abc import Iterable`, or similar), the package `collections` automatically gets the attribute `abc`.

This is what's happening here. When you do:

```
from b import B
```

the name `b` is automatically loaded into `test`, because `b` is a submodule of the `test` package.

Even if you don't do `import b` explicitly, whenever you import that module, the name is placed into `test`. Because `b` is a submodule of `test`, and it belongs to `test`.

---

**Side node:** your code won't work with Python 3, because [relative imports have been removed](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PortingPythonToPy3k#relative-imports). To make your code work with Python 3, you would have to write:

```
from test.b import B
```

This syntax is perfectly identical to `from b import B`, but is much more explicit, and should help you understand what's going on.

---

**Reference:** the [Python reference documentation](https://docs.python.org/dev/reference/import.html#submodules) also explains this behavior, and includes a helpful example, very similar to this situation (the difference is just that an absolute import is used, instead of a relative import).

> When a submodule is loaded using any mechanism (e.g. `importlib` APIs, the `import` or `import-from` statements, or built-in `__import__()`) a binding is placed in the parent module's namespace to the submodule object. For example, if package `spam` has a submodule `foo`, after importing `spam.foo`, `spam` will have an attribute `foo` which is bound to the submodule.
>
> Let's say you have the following directory structure:
>
> ```
> spam/
>     __init__.py
>     foo.py
>     bar.py
> ```
>
> and `spam/__init__.py` has the following lines in it:
>
> ```
> from .foo import Foo
> from .bar import Bar
> ```
>
> then executing the following puts a name binding to `foo` and `bar` in the `spam` module:
>
> ```
> >>> import spam
> >>> spam.foo
> <module 'spam.foo' from '/tmp/imports/spam/foo.py'>
> >>> spam.bar
> <module 'spam.bar' from '/tmp/imports/spam/bar.py'>
> ```
>
> Given Python's familiar name binding rules this might seem surprising, but it's actually a fundamental feature of the import system. The invariant holding is that if you have `sys.modules['spam']` and `sys.modules['spam.foo']` (as you would after the above import), the latter must appear as the `foo` attribute of the former.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can see that this does happen, but I don't understand why.
I found this in some working prod code, and wanted to understand why it works this way before I got rid of it.

Comment: @DeTeReR: what exactly you don't understand?

Comment: It makes sense that the module `test.b` is there (just like `os.path` is there when you import `os` since the `os` package also imports from `os.path`). That would explain why you could refer to `test.b.B` from `run.py`. But it’s not an explanation for why the `__init__` module of the `test` package suddenly has `b` *as a name* defined. There is nothing in `from b import B` that should make the name `b` locally available.

Comment: When you do `from b import B`, you are actually doing `from test.b import B` (this is a relative import). You are implicitly importing `test.b`, that's why `b` is being added to `test`

Comment: That doesn’t make any sense; just like doing `from os.path import isdir` or `from os import remove` declares neither `os` nor `path` in the module namespace, `b` also shouldn’t be available here. After all you are only importing the type `B` from that module. As per the [reference](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement): *“The `from` form does not bind the module name: it goes through the list of identifiers, looks each one of them up in the module found in step (1), and binds the name in the local namespace to the object thus found.”*

Comment: @poke: the line `from b import B` appears in `test/__init__.py`, not on a random module. `__init__.py` is that special file that represents the code for the Python package, it's not a module called `__init__` (it's the file that is imported when you do `import test`, it's not a module that you import via `import test.__init__` or similar)

Comment: It’s completely irrelevant to me where this `from b import B` line is. It shouldn’t matter that it’s in the package root—the package root is still a module. That line shouldn’t declare the name `b` *into that same module*.

Comment: @poke: but why a submodule should not appear as a name of its own package? You import a submodule and... it should just disappear? Why? :)

Comment: It’s absolutely clear to me that the *module* is imported. You can see that by looking at `sys.modules`. The `test.b` module is there, and should be there. That’s absolutely fine. But the local name, the variable `b` should **not** be declared by that `from b import B` statement. That’s what the whole `from…import` syntax is about, to not import the module as a name.

Comment: @poke: again, `test/__init__.py` is special. It is the parent of `b`, it is its responsibility to hold that name. This is how Python works and has always worked. I can't understand why you think a package should not hold a reference to its submodules, really. BTW, I edited the answer, hoping that it's clearer now.

Comment: Yes, it’s clearer now, thank you. Do you have any source for that though? Because I never heard that, and it seems very unintuitive to me.

Comment: @poke: there's no better source than the source code! :) But the reference documentation does a good job at explaining this. I updated the answer with the link

Comment: Very interesting, I learned something new today! The answer looks good to me now. Thank you for the patience and the explanations, Happy Holidays :)

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini to make this clear `__init__` will have the names of the `sub modules in the package` right ?

Comment: @VigneshKalai: yes, but only when imported. In the example from the Python reference, if you import only `foo` and not `bar`, you'll have `spam.foo`, but not `spam.bar`

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini ok so if you import in `__init__` it gets added else it will not. Thanks mate already upvoted it :).