# python relative import not working as expected

Tags: python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have the following module package organization

```
models
├── __init__.py
├── __pycache__
│   ├── __init__.cpython-34.pyc
│   ├── model.cpython-34.pyc
│   └── user.cpython-34.pyc
└── user.py

1 directory, 5 files
```

following are the contents of my `__init__.py`:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()

from .user import User
```

on running

```
>>> from models import *
>>> dir()
['SQLAlchemy', 'User', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', 'db', 'user']
```

> Notice that `user` is also in the list, whereas I explicitly did `from .user import User` inside `__init__.py`.

I am not able to understand this behavior, because if I simply do

```
>>> from models.user import User
>>> dir()
['User', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__']
```

I **only** get `User`.

How to achieve the same result with the `__init__.py` file, i.e. how to import *only* `db` and `User` and *not* `user`.

> Note: `user` is the module `user.py` and `User` is the class inside it.

Comment: Don't `import *`. It will import everything inside the module's public namespace.

Comment: @dirn i know, but `user` isn't inside the module's public namespace, right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Imports behave differently when in \_\_init\_\_.py that is imported](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34434749/imports-behave-differently-when-in-init-py-that-is-imported)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the line:

```
__all__ = ['User', 'db']
```

at the beginning of your `__init__.py`.

`__all__` whitelists the names that will be imported by `from module import *`.

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/2.1.html):

> Modules can now control which names are imported when `from module import *` is used, by defining an `__all__` attribute containing a list of names that will be imported. One common complaint is that if the module imports other modules such as `sys or`string`, from module`import * will add them to the importing module’s namespace. To fix this, simply list the public names in `__all__`:
>
> ```
> # List public names
>   __all__ = ['Database', 'open']
> ```